# how to use elastic search to search for similar word when typing the word?

Tags: elasticsearch

i use this query to search for full word when i type only p.so it will return result pepsi,pasta and so on. but i want this to show suggestion when im typing the letter/related words. for example , if i type p it should display suggestion while im typing the letter and a good example is stackoverflow while we typing the question its showing the related questions.

how i should do this in elastic search?

```
 POST /ecommerce/product/_search
{
 "from": 0,
 "query": {
  "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "name":{
          "query": "p"

      }
        }
     },
"size": 10,
"stored_fields": [
   "uid",
   "_source"
]
 }
```

Comment: You client application should send the query on every key stroke, that's how SO and everyone else do it

Comment: It's not quite clear what results do you expect besides those provided in an example with `match_phrase_query`. Could you give an example of results you expect to get but that are not returned by this query?

Comment: i run this query in sense and kibana and it is returning result . for example , if i type pa it will return result 'pasta','al pasta'. but im not sure whether match_phrase_query will show suggestions or not when user typing the word in real application. how to can check whether this query will show suggestion while user typing the word in sense/kibana 5.2.2?